# Unity C# Moving Platform Offset at Runntime

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, offset, translate

So I made some very simple moving platforms for my game.

```
public float speedX;
public float speedY;
public float length;
public float pause;

float timer;
Vector3 move;

void Start () {
    timer = 0;
}

void Update()
{
    if (timer == 0)
    {
        speedX *= -1;
        speedY *= -1;
        timer = length;
    } else
    {
        timer--;
    }
    if (timer > pause)
    {
        move = new Vector3(speedX, speedY, 0);
        transform.Translate(move * Time.smoothDeltaTime);
    }
}
```

When I play the scene I placed them in they run just fine. But when I play through the game and get to that scene, the platforms are all offset a little bit in whatever direction they were moving.
  Anyone have any ideas on how I can get the platforms to move consistently in different play sessions?

Comment: are they destroyed before getting to that scene?

Answer (score 3):

Time.smoothDeltaTime is not a constant rate so the distance your platform moves will change. These small differences will add up and displace the original position.

I would define start & end points and then move between them.  Check out these handy methods for some ideas: [Vector3.MoveTowards](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html) & [Vector3.Lerp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html)

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use a tween engine , like http://dotween.demigiant.com/.

If you install Dotween then you can simply use

```
transform.DOMove(new vector3(1 ,0 , 1) , duration);
```

You can also set Ease for tweens. or use Oncomplete fucntions;

```
transform.DOMove(new vector3(1 ,0 , 1) , duration)
    .SetEase(Ease.OutCubic)
    .OnCompelete(() => { shouldClose = true; });
```

You can also set loop for your tween `.SetLoops(-1)`.